# How can I merge several txt files into one including their names (with python)?

Tags: python

I want to merge several txt files into one file with Python. I already found a code for that:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

But I want to keep the names of the single txt files and have them printed above each txt file in the merged one. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Just write `f` (that's the name of the file) to `outfile` before you write the contents of the `infile`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! And how do I do that?

Comment: `outfile.write(f.encode())` perhaps? Maybe pad some new lines to it...

Comment: perfect! Now I have the file names in there, but how can I add a line break after them?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(bytes(f"{f}\n", 'utf-8'))
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It gave me the following error though:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

...

Comment: You are right the outfile is open as bytes ("wb") this version should work

Comment: that works! But is there a way to add a line break after the file names?

Comment: Yes check last version